# CSS background image transition "shakes" when transitioning

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have an image banner that rotates images by using jQuery to update the background-image property. When transition between two images the new image will "shake" until the transition is complete. The CSS for the banner is as follows:

```
div#reviewPanel {
    width: calc(100% + 100px);
    background: no-repeat center;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 -50px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: background-image 2s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-image 2s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #1f292d;
    max-height: 600px;
}
```

The height for the banner is set dynamically based on the screen size but is set before the background image is applied and the issue persists if I set a fixed height.

You can see an example here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/jbuckland/rs5eqhaj/

I have tested in Chrome and Safari on Mac, I'm not sure if the behavior exists in other browsers/OS.

I know this a relatively new CSS feature so I'm not sure if it's just a bug but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I am in the same boat

Comment: Not really, having all of the images be the same size was the only way I found to prevent it.

Comment: I don't see why you'd expect this not to happen. The transition is decreasing the opacity of the initial image whilst increasing the opacity of the next, so that you see one overlaying the other. If the text in each of the images isn't positioned at exactly the same location relative to the top and left of the image's canvas, which it won't be if the images are different heights and the text is vertically centred in each of them, the text will appear to shake. Using real images, your example behaves exactly as I'd expect: https://jsfiddle.net/gor5ut3d/